# Is a dedicated execution context for database queries(JDBC) always a good idea?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am creating a play application that connects a relational database(Amazon RDS).

The logics that make queries to the database are wrapped in `Future` for asynchronous execution.

Would setting up a dedicated execution context for the queries to separate from one used by the app bring any performance gains? if so why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. And that is the preferred way of dealing with such stuff in normal scenarios.

By default the thread-pool used by Play for handling requests, has a default size of the number of cores of the machine. To get the best performance out of the execution-context used by Play for handling requests, your action handler code needs to be:

> > Non-blocking and computationally fast

This is because, any blocking operation, or a computationally expensive-call, would take more time to execute. A few blocking requests clog the thread-pool, making no thread available to handle newer requests. Things get worse under higher load, as in such scenarios, you may want to return  back to the user with some message, rather than  the user waiting for too long  to get results (as all the threads are busy serving the previous calls).

Lets assume on a 4-core machine, if your action handler does a blocking a call (taking 10 seconds to execute). If there are more than 4 concurrent http requests, the server would not be able to process the new request (till the previous 4 are executed), even though the machine is under-utilized computationally. And the server can ideally take far more load.

So the action-handler code is expected to be written in a particular way to get the best out of Play.

Lets assume that you use the same execution-context used by Play for its request-handling threadpool, to  be used for db calls. A few expensive db calls, would clog the execution-context, making no thread available to handle requests.

Comment: So, the separation of the execution context is more or less for handling more requests(without blocking) and has nothing to do with the overall time it takes to handle a request?

Comment: The request may have to wait longer before it gets a thread from the thread-pool. Once it gets a thread, then it of-course depends on the body of the Action handler